# Issue in my sms gateway Integration I purchased from third party

Tags: php, sms

I am having issue in my sms gateway integration. I purchased from third party? I want to know how to get the delivery status? Here I will list the documentation also.kindly go ahead?How do I get my message Id from Api.

```
Get Delivery Reports
For checking delivery report use the URL given below:
http://t.dialmenow.info/getDLR.jsp?userid=username&password=password&messageid=1,2&externalid=1,2&drquantity=X&fromdate=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss&todate=yyyy-mm-ddhh:mm:ss&redownload=yes&responcetype=xml
messageid=>When you send a message you will get an unique message id from API and you have to use this
message id for getting the deliver status for that message.
```

Here is my sms code:

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
{
$mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];
$message=urlencode($_REQUEST['message']);
$ID = 'xxxx'; 
$Pwd = 'xxxxxx'; 
$url="http://t.dialmenow.info/sendsms.jsp?user=$ID&password=$Pwd&mobiles=$mobile&sms=$message&senderid =MEDVNN&messageid=1";
//echo $url;
$ret = file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ret);
echo $ret[9];
}
?>
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get the message id form delivery reports.
2. IF you see my $Text = 'welcome to US'; here I have another problem If I give space in $Text variable the message is not coming to my mobile

Can any one guide me what I have to do further.

Comment: 1. ask the "third party"; 2. check the documentation.

Comment: ok what about the my second issue statement? $Text = 'welcome to US' if i give space after any word the message is not going

Comment: I have given  the urlencode in $text.It Solves. why do we want to give urlencode?

Comment: As it's used in URL, you have to encode it; that's how `urlencode()` does.

Comment: I have updated the code Check this link:  http://tutorquery.comuv.com/sms/  mynumber is 9843110682 I have used  urlencode ,print_r ($ret). now with word after space is working. why do want to use urlencode. 
 kindly submit the form empty you can see  associative array  like this  [11] => -10015 here 10015 is the response for blank message like that  I am asking ?how do we identity the delivery report. once again read my question now you  will get idea?

Comment: Did you understand what is going  in the api? Now can you help me out?

Comment: always use `urlencode()` in URL parameters. I can't see a reason not to.

Comment: Have you checked my link?I want to know how do i get the delivery status.after reading documentation only I have given the link.I used print_r($ret) It gives associative array. please read my Get Delivery Reports In my question alteast you can guide me am i wright way?